# Working with minidump mdmp file

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, crash-dumps, minidump

I finish my application, it is already on windows store. Application work great but I still get errors from Microsoft Dev Center. A lot of bugs I resolved but Microsoft gave me minidump file.

I try to open it and check what it contains, but I think I opened it only in 20%

this is what I did

unpacking file.cab

```
(VS) file -> open file -> minidump.mdmp
(VS) Actions -> Debug with native only
```

but I got binary info from Visual Studio "not found"

Comment: This could be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx

Comment: Did you specify the creation of debug symbols when you built your release version of the app?  If so, you need to make sure the symbols and the associated binary files are available when you debug a mini-dump file.